# WPF or Windows Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, c#-4.0

I've been playing around with C# console applications for about a year and I want to move on to creating GUI applications. I have never done any GUI development besides basic Java applications, but I want to continue using C#. Should I start learning Windows Forms or jump straight to WPF? Is there a huge difference? Does WPF build on top of Windows Forms or are they totally different?

Comment: I found this site very intersting: https://www.educba.com/winforms-vs-wpf/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you're just starting out, jump straight into WPF.

It will allow you to get starting making rich interfaces using mark-up to define your interface without teaching you the possible bad habits (for WPF) that you'd learn from Windows Forms.

Comment: +1 I absolutely agree.  WPF is far more flexible than Windows Forms and it is the long-term in GUI development.  It's very close to HTML in how you use an XML-based layout.  The best argument for Windows Forms right now is if you have a dev team with major experience using it.  WPF is the future, and it already is leaps and bounds ahead of Windows Forms.

Comment: +1 but, WPF is only usable from .NET 4.0+ because of the font issues in previous versions, so keep that in mind for application deployment.

Comment: @Fauxide WPF is usable in .NET 3.5. There have been plenty of useful apps built...font issues aren't a show stopper for everybody.

Comment: +1 - Done WinForms for years, now in WPF. Never to look back ;) WPF is a lot nicer, a lot faster. Was using only 3rd party controls in winforms for years - now I use them, but not ONLY (i.e. the standard controls are usable, 3r party is not a replacement but new stuff). Especially with .net 4.0 - wpf rocks. Oh, and I do high performance data visualization (a.k.a. financial instrument trading application).

Comment: +1 WPF has a bit of steep learning curve, but once you've learnt it it's fantastically powerful. Make sure you start with the MVVM pattern though, it just makes sense.

Answer (score 25):

These two are totally different technologies. They do offer some interoperability layers to both directions, but other than that have nothing in common. Windows Forms is more or less a lightweight wrapper on top of [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)/[MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library), which means its extensibility in .NET is not that good in all cases. WPF is a new UI framework implemented from scratch. WPF is also much more flexible when it comes to customizing the existing types.

However, at least from my experience, Windows Forms seems to be the more commonly-used desktop UI framework in the industry. Windows Forms can't be used with web development though while WPF offers Silverlight and XBAP applications.

If you have done any UI development before, I'd dare say Windows Forms is easier to learn as it follows more traditional programming paradigms. The programming model of WPF is quite different to this. While WPF can be used in the same way as Windows Forms, most of its benefits are not achieved until you embrace the data binding and encapsulation WPF provides.

Despite stating some points in favor of Windows Forms choosing WPF over Windows Forms would be a no-brainer for me if all you want to do is learn a UI framework. It's superior to Windows Forms in all aspects. I just wish the software industry in general would adapt it on a larger scale! (Though not like anyone writes desktop applications any more since we got the web.)

Answer (score 10):

Both technologies have their pro's and con's.

WPF is better for cross platform development and creating 'flashy' GUI's.  However it requires a newer .net framework than WinForms and requires a dx9 compatible GPU or higher (which most people will have).

But it is a little bit more involved to create the interface / wire up all the events etc.

WinForms is still a powerful technology which can often be developed at a faster pace than WPF however, in the end, **both technologies can be used to achieve the same thing.**  However WPF is the 'newer' standard.

WinForms is commonly used to develop business applications whereas WPF is often used to create more end-user based bits of software, apps etc.

Answer (score 6):

WPF provides very rich facilities to build extremely complex user interfaces. It simplifies integration of a hardware-accelerated graphics in your interface. However, the Visual Studio WPF designer is really bad (I almost never use it). I also think that WPF is much more complex, and it is more difficult to start with. But this is subjective of course.